# Is there a simple way to load parquet files directly into Cassandra?

Tags: csv, import, cassandra, parquet

I have got a parquet file / folder (about 1GB) that I would like to load into my local Cassandra DB. Unfortunately I could not find any way (except via SPARK (in Scala)) to directly load this file into CDB. If I blow out the parquet file into CSV it'll just get way too huge for my laptop.

I am setting up a Cassandra DB for a big data analytics case (I've got about 25TB in raw data that we need to get searchable fast). Right now I am running some local tests on how to optimally design the keyspaces, indices and tables before move to Cassandra as a Service on a Hyperscaler. Converting the data to CSV is not an option as this blows up too much.

```
COPY firmographics.company (col1,col2,col3.....) FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Downloads\companies.csv' WITH DELIMITER='\t' AND HEADER=TRUE;
```

Comment: why not use Spark?

Comment: seemed like a lot of overhead for such a small task... and i was wondering if anyone else had come up with slimmer solution

Comment: from time perspective, it's easier to use Spark once (in the local mode) than to try to convert to CSV & load...

Comment: so you'd convert to CSV and then load? not rather directly via ```com.datastax.spark.connector```?

Comment: No, vice versa - just use spar.read.parquet and save via spark cassandra connector - that’s 2 or 3 commands in Spark shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, like [Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) said, it's easy enough to just write this up in SPARK. Below my code:

```
import findspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession  
findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Spark Exploration App")\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.2')\
    .getOrCreate()

import pandas as pd
df = spark.read.parquet("/PATH/TO/FILE/")

import time
start = time.time()

df2.drop('filename').write\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .mode('append')\
    .options(table="few_com", keyspace="bmbr")\
    .save()

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: HI-I would like to know what if I want to upload it to AWS Keyspace Cassandra DB?